# What happened to the error squiggles of the VsCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So I just updated the C/C++ Extension in VsCode (It is Version 1.7.0) and after that the Error Squiggles just stopped working. I tried everything (like enabling it in workspace and enabling it through command). For Ex
[image], in this I am trying to access a element bigger than the array and missing a semi-colon but it still doesn't work. Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: *I tried everything*  Did you try reverting to 1.6.0 from Aug 24?

Comment: Yes I did, I can but is there any way to fix it in 1.7.0